# How to remove required validation from WFFM hidden required fields in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, hidden-field, buttonclick, required, web-forms-for-marketers

I am working on WFFM Sitecore.

I have one droplist "Title" with option of

- Mr
- Miss
- other title

And one required text-box called `Other`.
The text-box is hidden on page load and it will be shown only when the user selects the **other title** option from droplist.

If we are selecting **Mr** or **Miss** then the `Other` text-box is hidden but it is still a Required field. When we submit the form it triggers the required field validation of the hidden `Other` text box .

How can I remove the required fields that are hidden on WFFM save action.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the "Required" flag from the field in the WFFM editor, and then add some custom JS validation that checks the **Title** field and if its set to `Other Title`, validate that the text box has been populated.

You can't do that in WFFM without custom JavaScript.

You would also want to make sure that your server code validates this again to protect against someone trying to bypass the JS validation.